# How can I set the margin for View only on iOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-hooks, cross-platform

I have the problem as below:
I have a View and I just want to set marginTop=20 for each iOS, and I do the following:

```
<View style={[styles.container,Platform === "ios" ? {marginTop:20}:{marginTop:0}]}>
</View>
```

But that code is not working. Can someone explain to me why and give me a solution?

Comment: You should be checking for Platform.OS instead of just Platform

Comment: @The1993 is right. You need to use Platform.OS

Answer (score 2):

You need to write Platform.OS === "ios".

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the style like this:

```
<View 
    style={[
      styles.container,
      { 
       marginTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : 0 
      }
    ]}>
</View>
```